# Create function with undefined variable calls dynamically

Tags: php, firebird, interbase

I'm working with a database making several inserts/updates and the process is very slow.

In the process of trying to fix it I found `ibase_prepare` and `ibase_execute` and now I'm working on a function to make all the updates and inserts with it.

The problem comes with the number of fields to insert/update, they are variable and I don't know how to make the call to `ibase_execute($query, $field1, $field2,..., $fieldx);`

Sometimes is 1, others 2, others more.

```
<?php
$dbh = ibase_connect($host, $username, $password);
$updates = array(1 => 'Eric',5 => 'Filip',7 => 'Larry');
$query = ibase_prepare($dbh, "UPDATE FOO SET BAR = ? WHERE BAZ = ?");
foreach ($updates as $baz => $bar) {
    ibase_execute($query, $bar, $baz);
}
?>
```

Any idea to work with? Is possible to define a function in execution time? on a stream or something like that?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) should be able to do what you want. Just put your fields into an array:

```
$result = call_user_func_array("ibase_execute", array("field1"); //Just 1 field
$result = call_user_func_array("ibase_execute", array("field1", "field2", "field3")); //3 fields
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
        $fields= new array(1,2,3);
        $result = call_user_func_array("ibase_execute", $fields);
        $fields= new array(a);
        $result = call_user_func_array("ibase_execute", $fields);

This should work correctly, I'll check it later.

Best regards,

P.S. I don't know how to format the text, dammit.